# Google fonts and webfont, should fonts load before or after page loads?

Tags: javascript, ajax, fonts

so I am using Google Fonts and their WebFont.load API

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js"></script>
<script>   WebFont.load({
        google: {
          families: ['xxx']
        }   }); </script><style type="text/css">
```

However, for some weird reason Google's page speed asks to remove render blocking : https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js

So my question, do you guys put this code in the footer? As I thought one of the reasons to use this API was to prevent render blocking in the first place

Comment: Check the [readme on its github page](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader). Synchronous and asynchronous ways are described there. Your code is a synchronous call, so you should put it in the `<body>` to prevent blocking. But if you use an async example described in readme, you can put that code in both `<head>` and `<body>`